# KDE Plasma 5 thrashes while charging an Android device by USB

Tags: automount, plasma-5

Plasma 5.24.7, Ubuntu Studio 22.04.

My Android tablet that I use as a performance controller was a bit low on battery, so I plugged it into an open port on my USB hub and selected "charge only"...

... whereupon Plasma's otherwise very useful Disks & Devices indicator proceeded to try to mount the tablet as a media storage device. This failed (because the device was set to charge only)... whereupon Plasma tried again, and it failed again... and it tried again, and it failed again... and it tried again, and it failed again...

At which point, I realized that the action of charging a device from a USB port conflicts with Plasma's aggressiveness in automounting any devices it sees. Not supported in this shell.

I then changed system settings to disable all automount options... and Plasma *still* insisted on trying to mount.

So how do I disable this behavior?

Comment: I would suggest plugging the table into a USB electric device. The USB port on a computer may not even have the power to charge a table. I have several computers and none of the USB ports on them can charge my tablet.

Comment: Of course that's better for charging... however... Plasma's behavior seems not well thought through in this area and I'm wondering if there's something I missed in the settings.